# Express-Generator error under error.jade file

Tags: node.js, express, pug, express-generator

I am **new** with NodeJs and express. After I type in terminal (**npm audit fix --force**) and I try to start server, it give me an **error**.

[image: Console error]

**app.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**error.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= message
  h2= error.status
  pre #{error.stack}
```

I make **another project** and when I try to start server, it give me the **same error**. If I don't run(**npm audit fix --force**), server starts **without errors**.

Order of terminal inputs:

1. npx express-generator
2. npm install
3. DEBUG=xxx:* npm start
   **Result => Server Start and runs OK**

After I put (4. **npm audit fix --force**)

1. ...
2. ...
3. ...
   Result => Server Start and don't run OK. If I enter in random page, undefined, gives me an error, an constantely in terminal.

**Routes**
[image: Route]

**index.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
```

Comment: did you did `npm install` or `npm-install` (as you telling in your answer)

Comment: Without -, I edited now

Comment: can you show me the `route/index.js` file in your direc

Comment: You need another file? @ME-ON1

Comment: i meant form the inside not the tree structure. open the file paste it here

Comment: Is after structure. I install socket and now it works. But I don't understand this error